# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open nodejs

Tags: nodejs

estoy tratando de hacer un menú para mi aplicación en nw.js
e creado este script, pero por alguna razón que desconozco, no funciona

```
let menus = document.getElementById("menucontent").innerHTML;
const fss = require("fs");
function menu(m) {
   if (m == "1") {
       let menus = fss.readFileSync("/config/configFiles/password.html",'utf8');
       menu = menus;
   }
   if (m == "2") {
       let menus = fss.readFileSync("/config/configFiles/username.html",'utf8');
       menu = menus;
   }
}
```

alguna idea?

Comment: podrías aclarar que significa "no funciona"? estás seguro que ese archivo si existe y si tienes la ruta correcta?

Comment: si, porque visual estudio me auto completa la ruta, como si el archivo existiera

Comment: Sin conocer mucho de `nw.js`, y leyendo algo de él por encima, `nw.js` funciona en el cliente, o sea en el navegador. Ese archivo no lo puedes leer desde tu estructura de archivos local. Si es eso lo que estás intentando me temo que no vas a poder (por restricciones del navegador). Tendrías que encontrar alguna forma de "servirlo" (creando un servidor, o no se si ya tengas uno creado en tu proyecto) desde el cual lo puedas servir

Answer (score 0):

Que te lo autocomplete visual estudio no significa que la ruta este correcta. Al poner `/` al principio le estas diciendo a node que estas en la raiz de tu disco duro (`c:` para windows y `/` para linux).

Suponiendo que tu fichero de configuración este así:

```
mi-proyecto/
    | menus.js
    | config/
        | configFiles/
            | username.html
```

Tu ruta debería ser así:

```
fss.readFileSync("./config/configFiles/password.html",'utf8');
```

Nota el `.` al principio, que es la ubicación actual del fichero.

Te dejo [un ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-uhzsh7?file=index.js)